# Drag and Drop move mouse a set distance before beginning drag

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, drag-and-drop

This is a duplicate to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068106/wpf-drag-distance-threshold) but that one does not have a sufficient answer, so could someone help me out with this?

I have a UserControl that is being dragged, but this UserControl is also clickable, so sometimes when you click you might move you mouse 1 pixel and it would think its dragging and dropping.  How can I set a delay or make the mouse have to move, say 5 pixels, before it does the dragging.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late and in vb.net, but it may be useful. My example is dragging TreeViewItems. You first have to capture the position where the MouseLeftButtonDown event was fired.

```
Private _downPoint As Point
Private Sub TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        _downPoint = e.GetPosition(Nothing)
End Sub
```

Then in your MouseMove event, check that you have moved a minumim distance before triggering DoDragDrop.

```
Private Sub TreeViewItem_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        _dragObject = sender.DataContext
        If _dragObject IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed AndAlso MovedMinimumDistance(e) Then
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tb, _dragObject, DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
End Sub

Private Function MovedMinimumDistance(e As MouseEventArgs) As Boolean
        Return Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(Nothing).X - _downPoint.X) >= SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance AndAlso
        Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(Nothing).Y - _downPoint.Y) >= SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance
End Function
```

I believe this clarifies this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068106/wpf-drag-distance-threshold).